# How to fix attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase

Tags: java, android

I know my question is duplicate.. I tried all the answer but i didn't get answer. Im getting only error.

**Here my code:**

```
public boolean clearTable(String table_name){    
     SQLiteDatabase db= null;
    try{
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("Delete from "+table_name);
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name ='"+table_name+"';");

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()){ db.close();}
    }
    return true;
}

 public boolean insertPlaceName(String placeName){
    SQLiteDatabase db= null;
    try {
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("placeName", placeName);
        db.insert("coveredArea", null, contentValues);

    }finally {
        //close the db  if you no longer need it
        if (db != null && db.isOpen()){ db.close();}
    }
    return true;
}
```

**My Logcat Error:**

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.xyz/databases/My.db
07-16 17:37:04.264 20730-20730/com.xyz E/SQLiteLog: (5) database is locked
07-16 17:37:04.267 20730-20730/com.xyz E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.xyz/databases/My.db'.
```

Please anyone help me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you checked that you working with only one instance of SQLiteDatabase?

Comment: Any chance to see `getWritableDatabase()`?

Comment: where do you call `clearTable` and `insertPlaceName`. if they are consecutive, don't close database in both of them, just do it once.